# R how to match numerics in a list to dates in a data frame

Tags: r

I have the following list, "dates", of numerics representing dates and associated values representing number of hours:

```
$`2012-08-01 20:05:37`

214 216

$`2012-08-01 22:05:32`

211
```

I have a data frame, "data", in which each row contains two sets of dates ("hour" and "time_point") and the difference in hours between the two dates ("diff"). I need to cycle through each element of "list", and find the corresponding "time_point" in the data frame "data" that is associated with the addition of list values to the numeric. For example, the first value associated with the first element in "list" should match with "time_point"  "2012-08-10 17:53:16" because 214 hours added to the numeric results in that date. The output can be a list or data frame of the dates. Any idea on how to do this?

```
    diff              hour        time_point    ID
70  214 2012-08-01 20:05:37 2012-08-10 17:53:16 18
71  215 2012-08-01 20:05:37 2012-08-10 18:53:21 18
72  216 2012-08-01 20:05:37 2012-08-10 19:53:16 18
73  217 2012-08-01 20:05:37 2012-08-10 20:53:21 18
74  218 2012-08-01 20:05:37 2012-08-10 21:54:51 18
75  219 2012-08-01 20:05:37 2012-08-10 22:53:31 18
218  206 2012-08-02 02:05:12 2012-08-10 15:53:16 24
316  200 2012-08-02 06:50:17 2012-08-10 14:53:16 28
490   53 2012-08-02 22:49:52 2012-08-05 03:50:18 44
491   54 2012-08-02 22:49:52 2012-08-05 04:50:48 44
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you're looking for this?

```
ll <- list("date1"=c(214,216),"date2" = 211)
f <- function(x) d[d[,"diff"] %in% x,"time_point"]
lapply(ll,f)
```

**Data**

```
d <- "diff              hour        time_point    ID
 214 '2012-08-01 20:05:37' '2012-08-10 17:53:16' 18
 215 '2012-08-01 20:05:37' '2012-08-10 18:53:21' 18
 216 '2012-08-01 20:05:37' '2012-08-10 19:53:16' 18
 217 '2012-08-01 20:05:37' '2012-08-10 20:53:21' 18
 218 '2012-08-01 20:05:37' '2012-08-10 21:54:51' 18
 219 '2012-08-01 20:05:37' '2012-08-10 22:53:31' 18
 206 '2012-08-02 02:05:12' '2012-08-10 15:53:16' 24
 200 '2012-08-02 06:50:17' '2012-08-10 14:53:16' 28
  53 '2012-08-02 22:49:52' '2012-08-05 03:50:18' 44
  54 '2012-08-02 22:49:52' '2012-08-05 04:50:48' 44"

d <- read.table(text = d,header = T)
```

Comment: This seems to give me more outputs than expected, as in more dates than I should have

Comment: Do you just want to match the first of the list elements? If so,  change the function `f <- function(x) d[d[,"diff"] %in% x[1],"time_point"]`

Comment: I wanted to match all of the values associated with all of the list elements. Your code almost does this, except it matches more dates than the number of associated values. For example, one element in list has 3 associated values but your code matches 4 dates.

Comment: It matches the "diff" variable that equals list elements. There must be duplicate "diff" values in your data set.

Comment: There may be duplicate "diff" variables within the entire dataset, but not within the "diff" values only pertaining to a specific date. I see now that it is picking up duplicate "diff" values. Is there a way to search for the "diff" values that are only associated with it's specific dates? For example, the first list element,`2012-08-01 20:05:37`, has the values 214 and 216, but these values should only match with "time_points" associated with the  "hour" of the same date. Not sure if I am explaining this correctly.

Comment: This might work: `f <- function(x) d[(d$hour %in% names(ll)[x]) & (d$diff %in% ll[[x]]),"time_point"]` and `lapply(1:length(ll),f)`